# Enable or Disable multiple controls in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, controls, formatting

What is considered the best way of enabling or disabling multiple controls in Silverlight at the same time (textbox, combobox, autocompletebox and the like)?

- I suppose I could bind the "IsEnabled" property of each control to a boolean property.  That property only exists for interactive controls and not textblocks.
- I could loop through the children recursively and set their properties appropriately, but that seems inelegant.
- Ideally, I'd like to just set some disable-like property on the parent container of the controls, giving even the TextBlocks a disabled look similar to a Windows form.

Is there a way to just disable the parent container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a ViewModel approach similar to the answer in [StackOverflow 1545844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545844/problem-with-itemtemplate-textblock/1546259#1546259)

By having a calculated IsEnabled property you can then bind the elements in the View which should be controled by this property.

Comment: This is the only real answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

Use the ContentControl Silverlight provides.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="GroupOfControls" >...Your controls...</ContentControl>

//Enable and Disable
GroupOfControls.IsEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I always create a ControlHandler Class that does all the updates on my controls. (Just to separate concerns)

Recently we had to reset all controls on the form and didn't want to loop through every single control.

All control-related data logic gets updated in the ControlHandler class.

We then only apply the values appropriate values / properties onto our controls.

This is a workaround but worked pretty well and also cleanly for us.

There are, of course, better ways to solve that..

Comment: Shaharyar... can you elaborate just a little?  Are you looping through the controls from your ControlHandler class, or are your controls implementing this some other way?  Thanks.

Comment: You could create your own controllers with a Handler-Interface which would be used to modify the controls. But that would mean to code a little more and extend each control you want to use and register it in a global / static list.

What I did was fairly simple. I know which controllers I use so I just hard coded the values. Pointers in C# can also be used to accomplish that! You could make a function which takes (ref Controller c) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into disabling multiple controls when fetching data from a web service.
The BusyIndicator control got me what I needed with very little effort.
Maybe it'll be a good enough solution for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with UserControl and set its IsEnabled property.

...